# how to check how many EditTexts are empty?

Tags: java, android

I have 10 editTexts, which I get the text from like so:

```
EditText naamField1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam1);
        EditText naamField2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam2);
        EditText naamField3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam3);
        EditText naamField4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam4);
        EditText naamField5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam5);
        EditText naamField6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam6);
        EditText naamField7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam7);
        EditText naamField8 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam8);
        EditText naamField9 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam9);
        EditText naamField10 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.naam10);
        speler[1] = naamField1.getText().toString();
        speler[2] = naamField2.getText().toString();
        speler[3] = naamField3.getText().toString();
        speler[4] = naamField4.getText().toString();
        speler[5] = naamField5.getText().toString();
        speler[6] = naamField6.getText().toString();
        speler[7] = naamField7.getText().toString();
        speler[8] = naamField8.getText().toString();
        speler[9] = naamField9.getText().toString();
        speler[10] = naamField10.getText().toString();
```

Admitted, it's not the most beautiful code, but how can I check how many of these strings, edittexts are empty?
so far I've tried

```
for (int i = 1; i==10; i++)
        {
            if (speler[i] == "")
            {
                numberOfPlayers = i--;
                break;
            }
        }
```

and

```
for (int i = 1; i==10; i++)
        {
            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(speler[i]))
            {
                numberOfPlayers++;
            }
        }
```

I've declared numberOfPlayers as 0 at the beginning of the code.

So yeah, if anybody could help or point me in the right direction, that'd be great.

Comment: to begin with, java arrays start at index 0.

Comment: In addition to that, use the loops like so : `for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)`. Also in the first loop, you're breaking out on the first occurence of an emply EditText.

Comment: I know that arrays start at 0, i just think this is more readable. thank you for your feedback though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
arrayList.add("Buffon");
arrayList.add("");
arrayList.add("Messi");
arrayList.add("");
int count= 0;
for(String player:arrayList){
    if(!player.equals("")){
        count++;
    }
}
Log.d("playercount", "currentPlayers: "+count);
```

This is how i would do it.

You have to create an ArrayList and you add your players. After adding them you can loop over the list and check if the String is empty or not.

Hope I could help you.

Comment: You should compare string using equals method
`if (!palyer.equals("")) {`

Comment: Thank you so much, I can finally continue with my project now. this problem took me an incredible amount of time.

Answer (score 4):

As already stated, you are starting with the wrong `index` since `Arrays` in Java have a base of 0 and your loop is wrong. Also, you are comparing strings wrong. It should be something like

```
for (int i =0; i<10; i++)
    {
        if (speler[i].equals(""))
        {
            numberOfPlayers = i--;
            break;
        }
    }
```

A possibly more efficient and safer way of doing it the way you have it is

```
for (int i = 1; i<speler.length; i++)
    {
        if ("".equals(speler[i]))
        {
            numberOfPlayers = i--;
            break;
        }
    }
```

This way if the array length changes you don't have to keep adjusting your `for loop` since it now isn't hard-coded. It also protects against `NPE` with switching the `.equals()` statements around.

Comment: I would personally also check `speler[i].trim()` To ensure its not just containing `whitespace`. Else great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You must put the values in the string array in the moment of checking. If you put them in the array let's say in OnCreate the values will be in the array and if u execute the loop lets say in some button click listener and in meanwhile the user changes the content of the text box your code in the listener will be wrong.

And you need to declare the string array first:

```
String[] speler = new String[10]; // array with indexes from 0 to 9 (nonresizable)
```

and then check with the loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
{
     if(speler[i].equals(""))
     {
        counter++;                          
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to check both two times, as you already assigning value from edit text to string array. so use

`for (int i = 0; i<=9; i++)
        {
            if (speler[i] == "")
            {
                numberOfPlayers = i--;
                break;
            }
        }`

Comment: You should compare string using equals method `if (speler[i].equals("")) {`

Answer (score 0):

**Improvement TIP**    :

```
private static final int EDIT_TEXT_IDS = {
    R.id.naam1,
    R.id.naam2,
    R.id.naam3,
    R.id.naam4,
    R.id.naam5,
    R.id.naam6,
    R.id.naam7,
    R.id.naam8,
    R.id.naam9,
    R.id.naam10}

...

EditText[] naamField = new EditText[10];
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  naamField[i] = (EditText) findViewById(EDIT_TEXT_IDS[i]);
  speler[i] = naamField[i].getText().toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about your output, you didnt mention though, compare string values using equals methos dude.

String a=new String("abc");
String b=new String("abc");

now, now, a!=b; // because it compares the memory where these String objects saved! (they are different objects)

and a.equals(b); is true; since equals method compares the value, which is abc.